# VSCode 'Run Python file' does nothing

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

Today I've encountered a very strange problem in Microsoft Visual Studio Code 2022. When I press the 'play' button to run my python code, nothing happens. This is true also with debugging.
There is no activity in either the built-in cmd or powershell terminals, but through these terminals I can run my code.

I have been using VSCode to write and execute Python code for months now with no issues - as recently as 10 hours ago! I have changed no settings or updated anything and I am at a loss.

I've checked the VSCode Python plugin and last update was 3 weeks ago, so unlikely that, but rolled it back anyway with no luck. I have also made sure my default terminal is cmd prompt, tried reloading and opening a new terminal, restarting PC, all to no avail.

Please help!

Comment: Just a silly double check, you have the file with the main function active in VScode when pressing run I presume?

Comment: Yeah thanks, had it working for a moment by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `n` to open a new window, then dragging the tab for the file I was trying to run into it... very odd

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. use the shortcuts F5
2. install and use the code-runner extension
3. reinstall vscode

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and apparently it was there because my previous workspace wasn't closed (that is also why ctrl + shift + n worked for you)

You can close it by clicking File -> Close Workspace

And then opening the .py file again solved the issue.